# libGDX sprite image not updating Event Handling InputHandler

Tags: libgdx, sprites, input, eclipse

I created a separate inputHandler class implementing InputProcessor. I'm using Event Handling (libgdx github page: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling)

```
public class inputHandler implements InputProcessor {
    private cheetah cheetah;
    private gameWorld myWorld;
    private float cheetahX;

    private float scaleFactorX;
    private float scaleFactorY;

    public inputHandler(gameWorld myWorld, float scaleFactorX,
            float scaleFactorY) {
        this.myWorld = myWorld;
        cheetah = myWorld.getCheetah();
        cheetahX = cheetah.getX();

        int midPointY = myWorld.getMidPointY();

        this.scaleFactorX = scaleFactorX;
        this.scaleFactorY = scaleFactorY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println(cheetahX);
        cheetahX += 5;
        System.out.println(cheetahX);
        return true;
    }
```

cheetahX is updating in the console, but not on the screen. When I click on the DesktopLauncher window, the console prints cheetahX + 5 properly, but the image of the cheetah sprite remains still.

gameWorld class:

```
public gameWorld(int midPointY, int gameHeight) {
    currentState = GameState.MENU;
    this.midPointY = midPointY;
    cheetah = new cheetah(33, midPointY - 15, 10, 29);
}

public void update(float delta) {
    runTime += delta;
}
```

gameScreen class:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    runTime += delta;
    world.update(delta);
    renderer.render(delta, runTime);
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assigning `cheetahX` to something or drawing with it? You did not post your drawing method or where you use `cheetahX` further on in your code.

I predict that `Cheetah` holds your `InputHandler` then you need this:

```
public class inputHandler implements InputProcessor {
    private cheetah cheetah;
    private gameWorld myWorld;
    private float cheetahX;
    public float getCheetahX() { return cheetahX; } // This line

    private float scaleFactorX;
    private float scaleFactorY;

    public inputHandler(gameWorld myWorld, float scaleFactorX,
            float scaleFactorY) {
        this.myWorld = myWorld;
        cheetah = myWorld.getCheetah();
        cheetahX = cheetah.getX();

        int midPointY = myWorld.getMidPointY();

        this.scaleFactorX = scaleFactorX;
        this.scaleFactorY = scaleFactorY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println(cheetahX);
        cheetahX += 5;
        System.out.println(cheetahX);
        return true;
    }
```

Now you can access it from cheetah. Somewhere in your update method you should grab it and assign the cheetah position with it.

```
public void update()
{
    position.x = inputHandler.getCheetahX();
    // Or
    batch.draw(cheetahTexture, inputHandler.getCheetahX(), position.y, ...);
}
```

I do not know how you draw or how you would like to use that variable so unless you supply all of your relevant code I cannot help you further.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem and my sprite is now moving perfectly :)

Comment: No problem and welcome to the SE network ;)